# Serialize two checkbox in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to serialize two input type checkbox but I am getting nothing, I am not sure if there is a problem with my code

```
<input class="CheckBox" id="Refs" value="13" type="checkbox">
<input class="CheckBox" id="Refs" value="14" type="checkbox">
```

And doing something like

```
$(".CheckBox:checked").serialize();
```

returns null

but

```
$(".CheckBox:checked").val();
```

has the first checked checkbox
Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Why do you need the `:checked` selector? Perhaps remove that part of the selector.

Comment: Ids are unique, you shouldnt have multiple elements with same id.

Answer (score 1):

Form elements need to have a `name` attribute to be `.serialize()`'d, since the `name` attribute is what's used as the pairs key during serialization.

Also note, the `id` must be unique document-wide:

```
<input name="a" class="CheckBox" id="Refs_a" value="13" type="checkbox">
<input name="b" class="CheckBox" id="Refs_b" value="14" type="checkbox">
```

Also, the `:checked` pseudo selector isn't neccessary, since un-checked checkboxes won't be serialized anyway - that'd defeat the point of a checkbox.

```
$(".CheckBox").serialize();
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9pe1f1sf/2/)

Comment: @JackM See my ***working*** [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9pe1f1sf/2/). How is your code different to what is in that fiddle? Is the down-vote from you?

Comment: my code is similar to yours I initially thought it was a case of names which were identical but now I can serialize when the name are the same but not when the names are the same. yup the downvote was mine

Comment: strange enough  $("input:checkbox").serialize(); serializes it

Comment: `input:checkbox` as oppose to what? What were you trying before? You won't need the `:checkbox` selector.

Comment: was trying $(".CheckBox:checked").serialize(); as in my question thanks